# Is there a method of doing close from the outside of the method of generating Statement and ResultSet generated from Connection?

Tags: java, resultset

I am Japanese. English is unskilled. I'm sorry. 
Is there a method of doing close from the outside of the method of generating Statement and ResultSet generated from Connection?

However, I want to `close()` it these one without calling `Connection#close().` 
I learn the instance of Connection from the outside of the method.

Answer (score 1):

No. JDBC requires you to `close` all these objects by yourself (and in finally blocks to be able to handle exceptions).

Closing just the connection should close all objects derived from it, but I would not depend on that, and it is better to close those as soon as possible anyway. The opposite is certainly not true (closing a ResultSet will not close the connection), and there is also no way to get the parent Connection from a ResultSet (which I think was the gist of your question).

I would suggest to not use JDBC directly, but a more friendly framework on top, at least something as minimal like Commons DBUtils, which takes care of cleaning up these resources.

Comment: I made a large amount of method. Therefore, it is thought that the quality is mortgaged if processing where close() is called by the batch is put by using the technology like AOP. 
Therefore, there is considerably a risk in the replacement now with Apache Commons.

Comment: It don't think AOP is a good solution here. Managing database connections should not be a "Crosscutting concern", i.e. scattered all over your project. It should be concentrated in a small set of classes. Your "business logic" (the code that knows the query") should have no need to mess around with the JDBC connection.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you open any connection or creating any Statement/ResultSet explicitly close them.
Always try to call this method after you done with your JDBC code

```
public  void closeResultSetAndStatement(final Connection connection,
            final Statement statement, final ResultSet resultSet) {
        try {
            if (null != resultSet) {
                resultSet.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.warn(
                    "Exception while resultset statement. Not Throwing Exception, Ignoring it.",
                    e);
        }

        try {
            if (null != statement) {
                statement.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.warn(
                    "Exception while closing statement. Not Throwing Exception, Ignoring it.",
                    e);
        }

        try {
                    if (null != connection) {
            connection.close();
                     } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.warn(
                    "Connection could not be closed. Not Throwing Exception, Ignoring it.",
                    e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the library named lombok is used, it is possible to do as follows. import java.sql.*; import lombok.Cleanup; public class TEST { public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { Connection conn = null; // Statement @Cleanup Statement cstmt = null; cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call 11111.22222(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}"); // Execute cstmt.executeBatch(); //write file code goes here } }As a result, because this library uses java6, I who is using java5 cannot use it though close() of Statement is automatically called.

Comment: There shouldn't be any issue whether you are using Java6 or Java5

Comment: It is thought that the thing that concerns Cross-Cutting Concerns should not be put in logic as long as it is possible to do.

Comment: Let if the resource is closed by JVM the code is always checking the null so you can rely on the code .This is just a safety to measure all resources are closed before going out of the program

Comment: I want to achieve 'Crosscutting Concern'.